# iPad - UITableView with UITextField - Autoresizing problem when orientation changes

Tags: ipad, uitableview, uitextfield, autoresizingmask

In my iPad split view application, I've a table view in detailed view as well. Each row has a text field. When orientation changes, the table field in table view is extending out of table view.
Can some one tell me how to set the auto resizing mask so that even when orientation changes, the text fields will be within the table view?

Comment: If your width is set to be flexible it should resize, however I'm seeing what I think to be a bug where on the actual device itself my textfields won't resize while being edited when you rotate the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add `tableview` as `subview` of `UIView` then:

```
[self.view setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
[tableView setAutoresizesSubviews:YES]; or set in IB
```

while creation of `cell` set like this:

```
[urcell setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
```

if u add `textField` as subview of `cell`. So that it will handle all of its `subviews` while orientation

Comment: Looking at Apple's documentation, the default for autoResizesSubviews on UIView is YES so it won't always be necessary to do this.